# Object not moving when keys are pressed

Tags: python, class, object, pygame, key-bindings

I just started learning pygame to create a simple game for a project. I have an object "Rectangle" which has a method which changes the x and y position. However, for some reason, the object doesn't move. I found some examples where the x and y are changed when a key is pressed and a new object is drawn with the new coordinates. However, rather than do that I want to call a method which will move that rectangle and not create a new one. What's the best way to do it?

My code:

```py
import pygame

#init the pygame and create a screen
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1080,720))
done = False

#colours
blue = (0,0,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255,0)

x = 540
y = 660

#starts the game clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#class for all of the objects on the screen
class shape():
    def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y):
        self.place = place
        self.colour = colour
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

#class for a rectangle
class rectangle(shape):
    def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y, length, width):
        super().__init__(place, colour, x, y)
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, pygame.Rect(x, y, length, width))

    def move_up(self):
        self.y = self.y + 3

    def move_down(self):
        self.y = self.y - 3

    def move_right(self):
        self.x = self.x + 3

    def move_left(self):
        self.x = self.x - 3


#main loop
while not done:

        #checking for game events
        for event in pygame.event.get():

                #quitting gamw when window is closed
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

        Rectangle = rectangle(screen, yellow, x, y, 30, 30)

        #detecting key presses
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:Rectangle.move_up()
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:Rectangle.move_down()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:Rectangle.move_left()
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:Rectangle.move_right()

        pygame.display.update() 

        #controls FPS
        clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: In most simple implementations, including `pygame`, there's no "memory" of the pattern that is "behind" the rectangle once you have drawn the rectangle. So, if you were to somehow "move" the rectangle,  how would you reconstruct the background patten in the space it has just vacated?   There's no general way.  That's why the standard approach is to blank the screen, and then re-draw all the visible objects from scratch (perhaps with updated positions) on every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually do is to create a new rectangle at the initial position in every frame. The position is of the rectangle is updated, but since a new rectangle is created in the next frame, the rectangles seems to be immovable.

Do not draw the rectangle in its constructor, but add a `draw` method to the class `rectangle`:

```py
class rectangle(shape):
    def __init__(self, place, colour, x, y, length, width):
        super().__init__(place, colour, x, y)
        self.length = length
        self.width = width

    def move_up(self):
        self.y = self.y - 3
    def move_down(self):
        self.y = self.y + 3
    def move_right(self):
        self.x = self.x + 3
    def move_left(self):
        self.x = self.x - 3

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.length, self.width))
```

Create a rectangle object before the main application loop and call the `draw()` method in the main application loop:

```py
# create rectangle object
Rectangle = rectangle(screen, yellow, x, y, 30, 30)

#main loop
while not done:

        #checking for game events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                #quitting gamw when window is closed
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True

        # detecting key presses and change location of the rectangle
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if pressed[pygame.K_UP]:Rectangle.move_up()
        if pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:Rectangle.move_down()
        if pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:Rectangle.move_left()
        if pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:Rectangle.move_right()

        # clear display
        screen.fill(0)

        # draw rectangle
        Rectangle.draw()

        # update diesplay
        pygame.display.update() 

        #controls FPS
        clock.tick(60)
```